# How do I combine two separate parsed jsonObjects into a single arraylist?

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist, string-parsing

I would like to combine two separate parsed jsonObjects into a single arraylist, then display the results as Strings?

I would like to store `summaryJsonObject` & segment in `storylineData`. When I step through the code using the debugger `summaryJsonObject` & `segment` both hold the raw json. The raw json data also shows in the logcat but `storylineData` remains null & unavailable throughout.

Here is the parsing code.

```
public class StorylineData {
    private static String date;
    private ArrayList<SummaryData> summary;
    private ArrayList<SegmentData> segments;
    private String caloriesIdle;
    private String lastUpdate;

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public ArrayList<SummaryData> getSummary() {
        return summary;
    }

    public ArrayList<SegmentData> getSegments() {
        return segments;
    }

    public String getCaloriesIdle() {
        return caloriesIdle;
    }

    public String getLastUpdate() {
        return lastUpdate;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public void setSummary(ArrayList<SummaryData> summary) {
        this.summary = summary;
    }

    public void setSegments(ArrayList<SegmentData> segments) {
        this.segments = segments;
    }

    public void setCaloriesIdle(String caloriesIdle) {
        this.caloriesIdle = caloriesIdle;
    }

    public void setLastUpdate(String lastUpdate) {
        this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
    }

    public static StorylineData parse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        if (jsonObject != null) {
            StorylineData storylineData = new StorylineData();
            storylineData.date = jsonObject.optString("date");
            storylineData.caloriesIdle = jsonObject.optString("caloriesIdle");
            storylineData.lastUpdate = jsonObject.optString("lastUpdate");
            storylineData.summary = new ArrayList<SummaryData>();
            storylineData.segments = new ArrayList<SegmentData>();
            JSONArray summariesJsonArray= jsonObject.optJSONArray("summary");
            if (summariesJsonArray != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < summariesJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject summaryJsonObject = summariesJsonArray.optJSONObject(i);
                    if (summaryJsonObject != null) {
                        storylineData.summary.add(SummaryData.parse(summaryJsonObject));
                        Log.d("storylineHandler", summaryJsonObject.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
            JSONArray segmentsJsonArray = jsonObject.optJSONArray("segments");
            if (segmentsJsonArray != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < segmentsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject segment = segmentsJsonArray.optJSONObject(i);
                    if (segment != null) {
                        storylineData.segments.add(SegmentData.parse(segment));
                        Log.d("storylineHandler", segment.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
            return storylineData;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The MainActivity looks like this: 
**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener{
    ..other variables here..

List<StorylineData> storylineData;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

...other ui elements here...

        mEditTextResponse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editResponse);
    storylineData = new StorylineData();


MovesAPI.init(this, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, CLIENT_SCOPES.....
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        toggleProgress(true);
        switch (mSpinnerAPI.getSelectedItemPosition()) {

... other cases here...
            break;
...other cases here...

        case 4: // Get Summary Day
            MovesAPI.getSummary_SingleDay(summaryHandler, "20150418", null);//Date changed to "20150117"
            break;



 Other cases here..
            case 10: // Get Storyline Day
                MovesAPI.getStoryline_SingleDay(storylineHandler, "20150418", null, false);//Date changed to "20150418"
                break;

  ...Other cases here..

    }

}

...   Other MovesHandlers here...

   private JSONObject summaryJsonObject;
    private List<StorylineData> storylineList;
    private JSONObject summariesJsonArray;

private MovesHandler<ArrayList<StorylineData>> storylineHandler = new MovesHandler<ArrayList<StorylineData>>() {
@Override
        public void onSuccess(ArrayList<StorylineData> result) {

        toggleProgress(false);

        storylineList = (List<StorylineData>) StorylineData.parse(summaryJsonObject);

            updateResponse( + storylineData.toString() + "\n" //displays true to layout view
                 result.add(StorylineData.parse(summariesJsonArray))+ "\n"
+Log.d("call result", result.toString()) + "\n" //displays 60 in layout view & com.protogeo.moves.demos.apps.storyline.StorylineData@52824f88, null]
                + Log.d("Log.d storylineHandler", storylineHandler.toString()) + "\n"  ); //returns 78 in layout view  & com.protogeo.moves.demos.apps.Mainactivity@234234 to log cat


            onFailure code here..

    }
};

public void toggleProgress(final boolean isProgrressing) {

 togglePregress code here..
}

public void updateResponse(final String message) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        public List<StorylineData> storylineList;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mEditTextResponse.setText(message);

  if (storylineData!= null) {
                for (StorylineData storylineData : storylineList) {
                    mEditTextResponse.append(("storylineData" + storylineData.toString()));
                }
}

        }
    });
}


 }
```

**HttpClass**

```
public static void getDailyStorylineList(final MovesHandler<JSONArray> handler,
                                             final String specificSummary,
                                             final String from,
                                             final String to,
                                             final String pastDays,
                                             final String updatedSince,
                                             final boolean needTrackPoints) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    /* Refresh access token if only AuthData.MOVES_REFRESHBEFORE days are there to expire current token */
                    AuthData.refreshAccessTokenIfNeeded();

                    /* Exchange the authorization code we obtained after login to get access token */
                    HashMap<String, String> nameValuePairs = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    nameValuePairs.put("access_token", AuthData.getAuthData().getAccessToken());

                   // if (specificSummary != null && specificSummary.length() > 0) nameValuePairs.put("specificSummary", specificSummary);//att

                    if (from != null && from.length() > 0) nameValuePairs.put("from", from);
                    if (to != null && to.length() > 0) nameValuePairs.put("to", to);
                    if (pastDays != null && pastDays.length() > 0) nameValuePairs.put("pastDays", pastDays);
                    if (updatedSince != null && updatedSince.length() > 0) nameValuePairs.put("updatedSince", updatedSince);
                    if (needTrackPoints) nameValuePairs.put("trackPoints", "true");


                    URL url     = new URL(MovesAPI.API_BASE + MovesAPI.API_PATH_STORYLINE + (specificSummary != null ? specificSummary : "") + "?" + Utilities.encodeUrl(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                    urlConnection.connect();

                    if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                        /* All other HTTP errors from Moves will fall here */
                        handler.onFailure(getErrorStatus(Utilities.readStream(urlConnection.getErrorStream()), urlConnection.getResponseCode()), "Server not responded with success ("+ urlConnection.getResponseCode() +")");
                        return;
                    }

                    String response = Utilities.readStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                    Object object = new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
                    if (object instanceof JSONArray) {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) object;
                        ArrayList<StorylineData> storylineData = new ArrayList<StorylineData>();
                        if (jsonArray != null) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject storylineJsonObject = jsonArray.optJSONObject(i);
                                if (storylineJsonObject != null) {
                                    storylineData.add(StorylineData.parse(storylineJsonObject));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        handler.onSuccess(storylineData);
                    } else {
                        handler.onFailure(MovesStatus.INVALID_RESPONSE, "Expected a JSONArray from server, but failed");
                    }

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    handler.onFailure(MovesStatus.UNEXPECTED_ERROR, "An unexpected error occured, please check logcat");
                }
          }
        }).start();
    }
```

**MovesHandler**

```
public interface MovesHandler<T> {//T stands for generic type

    /**
     * Implement this method to get success notifications along with the result
     * @param result : Result of the operation completed with this handler
     */
    public void onSuccess(ProfileData result);

    /**
     * Implement this method to get failure notifications along with the {@link MovesStatus} code and a brief message
     * @param status : Status code of the failure
     * @param message : A brief message about the reason behind failure
     */
    public void onFailure(MovesStatus status, String message);
}
```

Comment: So your parse function returns `null`? and are you only stepping through this function or also `SummaryData.parse()` and `SegmentData.parse()`?

Comment: Thanks Hank, not sure I understand (new to android).  Stepped through `SummaryData` & `SegmentData` all seems ok? Added MainActivity above & think the MainActivity's inner class `private MovesHandler<ArrayList<StorylineData>> storylineHandler = new MovesHandler<ArrayList<StorylineData>>()`  attempts to store `SumaryData.parse()` and `SegmentData.parse()` inside `ArrayList<StorylineData>`? So I wanted to combine jsonObjects then pass to MainActivity's `result` variable and display with `updateResponse`. But debug  shows `storylineData` & `summaryJsonObject` as null while logcat shows raw json?

Comment: In your `MainActivity`, I don't see `storylineData` being updated or passed into any function besides the initial constructor.

Comment: Each time I attempt to try and update storylineData or pass it to any function inside the MainActivity, I get the message "storylineData is never used" or "storylineData has already been assigned". I think I just need to see an example of how to do it which combines my MainActivity with my StorylineData class & and the data parsed within it?

Comment: I don't see you calling `StorylineData.parse()` anywhere in `MainActivity`

Comment: Tried for days to call `storylineData.pars()` in `MainActivity` & no luck. Tried again with your advise & included changes in my MainActivity above. Added for loop based on your example in my `updateResponse`. My `onSuccess` now includes: `storylineList = (List<StorylineData>) StorylineData.parse(summaryJsonObject);` & `                     result.add(StorylineData.parse(summariesJsonArray))`. TextView now displays "true". `Log.d` in MainAcitvity causes textView to show the number of strings i.e 60 & log cat shows: com.protogeo.moves.demos.apps.storyline.StorylineData@52824f88, null] ?

Comment: You can't just call `toString()` on a `List`, that will just return the address location of the `List`. And from your code, it looks like you just want to print  `summary` and `segment` separately and not combined.

Comment: I am still learning & did not know you can't call `toString` on a list. I have no idea how to combine summary & segment & that's why my code is misleading, I was just trying what I hoped would work. Can you suggest a way to combine `summary` & `segment` & store them in `StorylineData`.  Then use `storylineData` in `MainActivity` to display the `storylineData` json in the `textView` as Strings?

Comment: Why don't you just call `toString()` on `summariesJsonArray`? Look at, http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#toString()

Comment: Thanks I've read the documentation & many tutorials but still cant work out how to implement `summariesJsonArray.toString` in my `MainActivity` or `StorylineData` class? Can you provide an example please?

Comment: Look at my edit in my answer, I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do in your MainActivity, but this would allow you to print the combined `segment` and `summary` JsonArrays

Comment: Thanks so much for your example. I have been trying to make the amendments but the thing is your example doesn't take into account that my `StorylineData` & `MainActivity` classes are both using/linked to my `HTTPCalls` & `MovesHandler` class'. So I now get errors in my `HTTPCalls` & `MainActivity` class after making your most recent suggested changes to `StorylineData` & `MainActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to have one `ArrayList` to store both `SummaryData` and `SegmentData`, you could just created an ArrayList of Objects, `ArrayList<Object>`. This would be the more general solution.

The alternative would be having `SummaryData` and `SegmentData` inherit the same class or implement the same interface.

Using an extended class, you could have:

```
class Data {
}

class SegmentData extends Data {
}

class SummaryData extends Data {
}
```

You could then have an ArrayList that would be able to add both `SegmentData` and `SummaryData` objects.

If you wanted to show each item as a String you would need to loop through the list and call the `toString()` function of each item

```
ArrayList<Data> dataList;
for (Data d : dataList) {
    Log.d("data", d.toString())
}
```

Just make sure to overwrite the `toString()` function in `SegmentData` and `SummaryData`

**EDIT: Showing how to print `JsonArray`**

If you wanted to just print for JsonArrays, you could:

```
public class StorylineData {
    private static String date;
    private JSONArray summary;
    private JSONArray segments;
    private String caloriesIdle;
    private String lastUpdate;

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public JSONArray getSummary() {
        return summary;
    }

    public JSONArray getSegments() {
        return segments;
    }

    public String getCaloriesIdle() {
        return caloriesIdle;
    }

    public String getLastUpdate() {
        return lastUpdate;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public void setSummary(JSONArray summary) {
        this.summary = summary;
    }

    public void setSegments(JSONArray segments) {
        this.segments = segments;
    }

    public void setCaloriesIdle(String caloriesIdle) {
        this.caloriesIdle = caloriesIdle;
    }

    public void setLastUpdate(String lastUpdate) {
        this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
    }

    public static StorylineData parse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        if (jsonObject != null) {
            StorylineData storylineData = new StorylineData();
            storylineData.date = jsonObject.optString("date");
            storylineData.caloriesIdle = jsonObject.optString("caloriesIdle");
            storylineData.lastUpdate = jsonObject.optString("lastUpdate");
            storylineData.summary = jsonObject.optJSONArray("summary");
            storylineData.segments = jsonObject.optJSONArray("segments");
            return storylineData;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        JSONArray combined = new JSONArray(summary);
        combined.put(segment);
        return combined.toString();
    }
}
```

In your **MainActivity**

```
private StorylineData storylineData;

private MovesHandler<JSONArray> storylineHandler = new MovesHandler<JSONArray>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(JSONArray result) {
        toggleProgress(false);
        storylineData = StorylineData.parse(summaryJsonObject);

        updateResponse(storylineData.toString()) //displays true to layout view
        result.add(storylineData.getSummary());
        Log.d("call result", result.toString());
        Log.d("Log.d storylineHandler", storylineHandler.toString()); 
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure how to override `toString` or implement your suggestions into my code? I'm trying to adapt existing code, so its easier for me to understand and implement could you show your answer and examples using my code, variables, class names etc & where they fit in my code please. As the Data and data list examples you provided are a bit hard for me to understand how to implement as a a beginner. Hopefully the MainActivity I included above helps, thanks again.

Comment: you can override `toString` by just implementing that function in `SegmentData` and `SummaryData`. And you should look up inheritance in Java to understand the Data example I provided. Inheritance is pretty common in Java and object oriented programming.

Comment: I've read up on inheritance & have some understanding of how sub-lasses inherit from the parent class. But I still can not see how to apply that to my existing code or if I write new classes based on your Data class example I can not see how to integrate that with the rest of my existing classes which are linked?

Comment: If I write a classes based on your `Data` example I can't see how to integrate it with the rest of my linked classes? I'm a bit confused with JsonObjects/Arrays so sure how to add both `SegmentData` and `SummaryData` objects within a new class. I believe `MainActivity's` inner class or `StorylinData` class may already offer opportunity for a beginner to add `SegmentData` and `SummaryData` without writing new class', which may b difficult for a newbie?